# Powershell command does not work when inputed into CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I was trying to start a shortcut from CMD (Time and date from control panel) which did not work, so I tried to do the same in Powershell where it did.

In Powershell I wrote this command and it worked first try.

```
cd 'C:\Users\JakubLL\Desktop\Zástupci!' ; start '.\Datum a čas – zástupce.lnk'
```

But for some reasone this is not the case if I try to run the exact same command in CMD.

When I try this command:

```
powershell -command "& {cd 'C:\Users\JakubLL\Desktop\Zástupci!' ; start '.\Datum a čas - zástupce.lnk'}"
```

> where the command inbetween brackets is copied from Powershell it self

the return is this:

```
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.
At line:1 char:46
+ ... rs\JakubLL\Desktop\Zástupci!' ; start '.\Datum a čas - zástupce.lnk'}
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

**Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.** translates to: **System cannot find the file specified.**

For some reasone CMD wil change the spaces between the word `čas` and `zástupce` to different ones.

> To be exact these spaces `čas – zástupce`

Powershell's spaces looks like this in binary (dash included)  `00100000 11100010 10000000 10010011 00100000`

When I copy the command pasted in CMD it looks like this (dash included) `00100000 00101101 00100000`

Can please someone help me with this. And also sorry if my english is not the best.

> **EDIT: It is not the spaces but the dash it self!**

Answer (score 0):

`start` is an alias for `Start-Process`. Aliases should not be put into code. They are helpful at a console for less typing, but that is as far as they should go.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Start-Process -WorkingDirectory 'C:\Users\JakubLL\Desktop\Zástupci!' `" ^
    "    -FilePath '.\Datum a čas – zástupce.lnk'"
```

If you believe cmd.exe is changing the spaces, put the `Start-Process` command into a doit.ps1 file and invoke it with:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\doit.ps1'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to use this`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File doit.ps1` intead of your comman because it was giving me this error

_`Processing -File ''.\doit.ps1'' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.`_
**Still thank you a lot, this actually helped me a lot**